# Cauchy_Schwarz Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When does equality hold in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$\vert x\cdot y\vert\leq\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$ for vectors $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$?

Can someone please show me how to answer this in full? It was in a test a few weeks ago and is still bugging me as the answer has not been posted yet. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I think it's when $x$ and $y$ are collinear, but I'm not sure

Comment: When $x=\lambda y$ for a constant $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. but the Cauchy schwarz inequality is not complicated : write $x = C y + u$ where $\langle u,y \rangle = 0$, then $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle C y+u,y \rangle = \langle C y,y \rangle = C \|y\|^2$. finally, $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle = \langle Cy+u,Cy+u\rangle = |C| \|y\|^2 + \|u\|^2$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the sleek inequality : $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (a_ix-b_i)^2 \geq 0$ that when expanded and collect like terms will be a quadratic inequality that holds for all $x$. This means $\triangle \leq 0$ and the inequality follows. From this you can see that $=$ occurs when $a_1x-b_1 = a_2x-b_2 = ... = a_nx-b_n = 0 \implies a_i = rb_i$ for all $i$

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that $|x \cdot y| \le |x|~|y|$, with equality if and only if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.  This happens when either $x=0$ or $y=0$ or both are nonzero but one is a (positive or negative) scalar multiple of the other.

If you want to derive this condition, go through the proof of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and examine where the inequality appears.